# Injecting an instance of drools StatefulKnowledgeSession during unit testing

Tags: spring, mockito, drools

```
public class App {

    @Autowired
    private KnowledgeBase kBase;

    private StatefulKnowledgeSession statefulKnowledgeSession;

    public void method() {
        statefulKnowledgeSession = kBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

        statefulKnowledgeSession.fireAllRules();
    }


}
```

I am working on a spring application that has a class of the form shown above.

The test class is of the form shown below

```
public class AppTest {


    @Spy
    private StatefulKnowledgeSession statefulKnowledgeSession;


}
```

The test class shown above does not contain the complete code but it is just to tell how the class looks. Now I want to fire the rules during unit testing by calling the actual method but I am not able to use @Spy as StatefulKnowledgeSession is an interface. @Spy needs an object to be created but I cannot obviously instantiate an interface.

Please Help!

Comment: can't you just see what concrete implementation of `StatefulKnowledgeSession` you are getting in our test, cast it and then spy it?

Comment: I debugged the code to check the class name, but the only thing that was being shown was StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl which means implementation of StatefulKnowledgeSession

Comment: Well, that's your concrete class